# Kohana 3.2 regenerating session id on every request

Tags: kohana-3

i hope this hasn't already been answered, I've looked through for awhile and haven't really seen an answer.

I am using Kohana 3.2 sessions with database driver. The problem is that every time the page is loaded or refreshed, it is creating a new session id.

I've set the Session::$default = 'database' in my bootstrap. My session config looks like this:

```
return array(
    'database' => array(
        /**
         * Database settings for session storage.
         *
         * string   group  configuation group name
         * string   table  session table name
         * integer  gc     number of requests before gc is invoked
         * columns  array  custom column names
         */
        'name'     => 'trucero_session',
        'lifetime' => 1200,
        'group'    => 'default',
        'table'    => 'sessions',
        'gc'       => 500,
        'columns'  => array(
            /**
             * session_id:  session identifier
             * last_active: timestamp of the last activity
             * contents:    serialized session data
             */
            'session_id'  => 'session_id',
            'last_active' => 'last_active',
            'contents'    => 'contents'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on the session ID because it's indeed regenerated on every request. If you need some sort of ID, you'll have to use a custom one.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... I've set and been using a custom session id... I guess my question should have been is this normal/okay? The session data is there and accurate, I just get a database table full of sessions... It also doesn't seem to be deleting them... I set the gc at 1200 just to give it a shorter lifetime to see if I could see if it was deleting.

Comment: Yes this is normal that the session ID is regenerated, however it should still delete old sessions when they are expired. In `modules\database\classes\kohana\session\database.php::_gc()`, you'll see the deletion code. Indeed, you could try with a short lifetime to see if the deletion code is fired.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Laurent really understood your question, because there should be only one single session id created and used between page refreshes - that's the whole point of having sessions is so you can re-use the same session every time when you access a page.

A new session ID is created when you open the page either with a new browser, or close the existing browser and then open a new one, or destroy the current session (like by logging out from your page) and then create a new one (..by logging in).

But I did find a similar problem in Kohana 3.2 where my scripts were generating multiple session IDs per each page read and the sessions weren't being "read" back because a new session_id was created at each page refresh/access. I was able to track this issue down to Google Chrome browser (in my case) and after digging around I found this post:

http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/10303/session-problem-with-ie-and-chrome/p1

Which basically says that you have to set Cookie::domain to either FALSE or to a specific domain for the Kohana database session to work properly in Chrome and in IE.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue (Kohana 3.1). Setting Cookie::domain as described in this answer didn't fix the issue however.